# How do I use a phrase with php in a mongo text search?

Tags: php, string, mongodb, escaping

I've got a simple mongo query which returns the result I want -

```
db.properties.findOne({$text:{$search:'\"Eiffel Petit Louvre\"'}})
```

However I can't seem to transpose the same query into php -

```
$searchString = '\"Eiffel Petit Louvre\"';
$hotel = $db->properties->findOne(
        array('$text' => array('$search' => $searchString))
);
```

This doesn't give me any results back. What am I doing wrong? I'm guessing it's the string. I've tried escaping the backslashes (I don't think I should need to since the string uses single quotes), but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the exact same problem. After long trial and error I figured out that the following works:

```
array('$text'=>array('$search'=>"\"$searchString\""))
```